# nodejs bing-chat text is empty

Tags: node.js

I'm using bing-chat library

I followed the docs and make a mjs file

However, I got empty with the text.

here is my code:

```js
import { BingChat } from 'bing-chat';
async function example() {
    const api = new BingChat({
        cookie: {_U},
    });
    const res = await api.sendMessage('Hello World!')
    console.log(res)
}

example();
```

I got:

{
author: 'bot',
id: 'xxx',
conversationId: 'XXX|BingProdUnAuthenticatedUsers|xxx',
clientId: 'xxx',
conversationSignature: 'xxx',
invocationId: '2',
text: ''
}